# Is my troubleshooting going out of scope?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question, etiquette

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887903/save-outlook-mail-into-individual-txt-files-in-to-system-folder) that I believe has gotten the user to a point where he should be able to figure out the answer on his own. However, the comments on the question are going back and forth a lot. I don't know at what point I should just stop trying to help. We seem to be going back and forth and not reaching a logical conclusion. One of us isn't understanding the other. I can't initiate a chat with the OP, so our comments are numerous.

Is there a point where you just need to stop? I have no intention of stopping for this question as of yet, but am I doing myself, the OP, or the community a disservice in how I am proceeding?

Alternatively, do you have a solution or suggestions on how I can handle this scenario?

Comment: You don't *have* to stop, but if you want to, [this Meta SE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478) on exiting "chameleon questions" might be of interest. I'm not too sure if helping specifically would be encouraged or discouraged, though (and I'll hold off on commenting on your specific situation for more knowledgable users); I'd imagine it depends on what the user you're helping does.

Comment: I dont feel bad for not looking up "chameleon questions". You comment help get me to the right answer. Please make and answer and i will mark it complete. It also gave me some tips about Q&A in general.

Comment: Not sure if I should post an answer, because I didn't really answer your question as stated. Glad to hear I helped you find an answer, though.

Comment: I updated my question so that it would fit your comment as an answer.